# Is there a way to call 6502 assembly code from C file?

Tags: c, 6502

I am using cc65 6502 simulator, which compiles code for 6502. I wish to link the 6502 code and C code and produce a binary file that I can execute.

My C code "main.c":

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 extern void foo(void);

 int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
 }
```

My 6502 code "foo.s":

```
 foo:
      LDA #$00
      STA $0200
```

The code might seem very simple but I am just trying to achieve the successful linking. But I cannot get rid of the following error:

`Unresolved external '_foo' referenced in:
 main.s(27)
 ld65: Error: 1 unresolved external(s) found - cannot create output file`

Comment: simply decorated name in *c* must be exactly to called name from *asm*. and visa versa. if you use `__cdecl` as default calling convention - the decorated (full) name of `foo` will be `_foo` - and in asm file you need use `_foo` name instead of `foo`. also name must be public (visible). the label usually not. you need declare `_foo` as public symbol. or as function (functions usual public symbols). however this depend from concrete asm compiler. now, when you build - you got error - unresolved external symbol (`_foo` i guess) - exactly this name you must implement in asm

Comment: I tried naming the asm file to `_foo.s` and in the main.c I changed the function name to `_fib`, but I still cannot get rid of that error.

Comment: Your .s file isn't declaring a function. foo: is just a label. In order for it to appear as a linkable symbol, you will need to add some additional (assembler-specific) directives to the file.

Comment: `cl65 -t sim6502 main.c _fib.s -o fib` yes, this compiles the C for 6502,  https://github.com/cc65/cc65

Comment: In foo.s, you just have to replace `foo:` with `_foo:` because the function foo in C language is converted into the symbol _foo by the compiler.

Comment: It's even part of the intro https://cc65.github.io/doc/intro.html#ss1.2

Answer (score 6):

You need to export it from the assembly module - with the same decoration the C compiler uses:

```
_foo:
.export _foo
      LDA #$00
      STA $0200
```

This links with:

```
cl65 -t sim6502 main.c foo.s -o foo
```

You might also need to look into the [calling conventions](https://cc65.github.io/doc/cc65.html#s5).